# Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit

Tags: mysql, node-modules

I am doing an insert to a mysql database, but I get the following error:
Error: Cannot enqueue Quit after invoking quit.

I share with you the code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'sql141.main-hosting.eu',
  database: 'u466684088_prueba_1',
  user: 'u466684088_prueba_1',
  password: 'Prueba_1prueba_1'
});

const conectar = () =>{
    connection.connect((error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error de conexión: ', error);
          return;
        }
        console.log('Conexión establecida a la base de datos MySQL');
      });
}

const  agregarDatos =(accoun_number,campain_number,channel,offer_type,offer_sub_type,customerid)=>{
  conectar();
  const sql=`INSERT INTO u466684088_prueba_1.save_data (account_number, campain_number, channel, offer_type, offer_sub_type, customerid)
                VALUES (${accoun_number},${campain_number}, ${channel}, ${offer_type}, ${offer_sub_type}, ${customerid})`;
  connection.query(sql,function(error,res){
    if (error) {
      connection.end();
    }
    connection.end();
  })
 }
```

Can you help me, please.

I'm trying to run an api without it being chashed

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error, `connection.end()` is called twice which seems to correspond to the error message.

```
if (error) {
  connection.end();
}
connection.end();
```

Note the insert multiple values from of `connection.query` to avoid SQL injection and probably the error. Database name can be removed from the query as its the default in the connection.

```
const sql= "INSERT INTO save_data (account_number, campain_number, channel, offer_type, offer_sub_type, customerid) ?"
var values= [ ${accoun_number},${campain_number}, ${channel}, ${offer_type}, ${offer_sub_type}, ${customerid} ];
connection.query(sql,function(error, [values], res){
```